# Soundtrack of K: Return of Kings - episode 1 at 19:16

Tags: music, k-project

What is the title for the song in K: Return of Kings episode 1 at 19:16, in the scene where Jungle throws a bomb and Homra and Scepter use a shield?

Answer (score 1):

That would be the second song on the K - Return of Kings OST, which is likewise called ["Return of Kings"](http://k-project.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_kings).